# FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP empty

Tags: php, regex, filter-input

I am trying to validate a field with php. I pass the value with POST, and it must contain only numbers and pipi ("|").

I'm using filter_input to check if the value validates:

```
filter_input(INPUT_POST,"q",FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP,array("options"=>array("regexp"=>"/^\s{0,}[0-9|]{0,}\s{0,}$/"));
```

This regular expression validate numbers, "|" and optional spaces before and after. This should validate also empty field, but this isn't. If the field is empty the filter_input return FALSE.

How can I validate also empty field? I want accept also empty as valid.

All works when the field date is compiled. When date is empty the date is not validated.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex matches an empty string as it is

with an input of nothing you get

```
string '' (length=0)
```

When the input is missing however thats a different case.

this is documented

> or NULL if the variable_name variable is not set.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php

casting to a string will "work" as null casts to an empty string

so

```
(string) filter_input(INPUT_POST,"q",FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP,array("options"=>array("regexp"=>"/^\s{0,}[0-9|]{0,}\s{0,}$/"));
```

will work as you expect

the casting documentation

> NULL is always converted to an empty string.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting

Comment: With FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP I botain only boolean (TRUE/FALSE) value, not a string.
I pass the parameter with POST: page_name.php?q=
and validation fails...